# Ajax response inside a div

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to show the value of ajax response inside a div and for that I have the following code in my view file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MY LINK TO JQUERY"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){ // added
     $('a.vote').click(function(){
         var a_href = $(this).attr('href');

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>contents/hello",
            data: "id="+a_href,
            success: function(server_response){
                             if(server_response == 'success'){
                                  $("#result").html(server_response); 
                             } 
                             else{
                                  alert('Not OKay');
                                 }

                      }
  });   //$.ajax ends here

  return false
    });//.click function ends here
  }); // function ends here
 </script>

  <a href="1" title="vote" class="vote" >Up Vote</a>
  <br>
  <div class="result"></div>
```

my Controller (to which the ajax is sending the value):

```
function hello() {
              $id=$this->input->post('id');
              echo $id;
             }
```

Now what I am trying achieve is get the server_response value (the value that is being sent from the controller) in side `<div class="result"></div>` in my view file.

I have tried the following code but its not showing the value inside the div.

Could you please tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Please spend the time indent your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you have mixed arguments of [Ajax `success` handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). First goes `data` which your script gives back, then goes `textStatus`. Theoretically it can be "timeout", "error", "notmodified", "success" or "parsererror". However, in `success` textStatus will always be successful. But if you need to add `alert` on error you can add `error` handler. And yes, change selector in $("#result") to class. So corrected code may look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>contents/hello",
    data: "id=" + a_href,
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        $(".result").html(data);    
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Not OKay');
    }
});​
```

Comment: the textStatus in the `success` handler is always `success`... isn't it?

Comment: Hm. Practically should be. However it is documented. Let me check.

Comment: True. I found proof. Stupid thing. Updated.

Comment: Stop. It also could be `notmodified`. However, it is also successful :)

Comment: LOL, you didn't notice the div `class` is result and not the id.

Comment: @gdoron This is the next problem :D

Comment: @VisioN Thanks for your reply. I had to replace `$("#result").html(data);` to `$(".result").html(data);` to make it work. But your answer was also really helpful. thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575928/ajax-response-inside-a-div/10575951#comment13694122_10575951 `:)`

Comment: Yep, take one from me free of charge... :)

Comment: Thanks! Seems like a day of presents :)

Answer (score 6):

```
success: function(server_response) {
        $(".result").html(server_response);
}​

<div class="result"></div> // result is the class
```

The selector should be `.result` not `#result`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `<div class="result"></div>` to `<div id="result"></div>`, because that's what you're referencing in your ajax success function

`$("#result").html(server_response);`