# AJAX being stubborn?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've been struggling with some AJAX. Here's my code, if anyone could point me in the direction of where I'm going wrong it would be a great help!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>

  <style media="print">
    #goBack,
    #printRow {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body id="body" class="body">


  <table>
    <form id="addUser" onsubmit="return false;">
      <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td>
          <input name="user" />
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
          <button id="createUser" name="submit" onclick="getAddUserStatus()">Add User</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td>
          <input name="pass" type="password" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </table>

  <div id="container" class="container">
    div contents here
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
  <script>
    function getAddUserStatus() {
      $('#addUser').on('submit', function() {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'response.php',
          data: postData,
          type: "POST",
        }).done(function(data) {
          console.debug(data);
          marker = JSON.stringify(data.message);
          console.debug(marker);
          alert(marker);
          $('.container').html(marker); // Or whatever

        });
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically where I'm asking for help is that I need to write the response of the json to the DIV, an example json response is

```js
Object {
  saved: false,
  user: "discoverexcel",
  message: "User already exists"
}
```

I've figured out how to obtain just "message" from it and throw it into an alert, but no luck with the DIV.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong at all.

Next big thing is, why is the page reloading?  I was under the impression that was a good reason to use AJAX, so anything here is greatly appreciated as well!

Also, my last question is, if I was to do multiple ones of these on a page, how would I go about doing so?  Nesting each one in a new function for each time they're clicked?  Also, what about a loading image to appear to show the status?

Comment: submit button submits....Cancel it

Comment: Please fix your markup... do not add spaces in between tags. Do not have a random `</meta>` at the end of your page. I'm not even entirely sure it will be parsed correctly. It sounds like @epascarello is right though so you might need to include `e.preventDefault()` in your JavaScript. You can [validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) here.

Comment: Got that taken care of, thank you! @epascarello

Comment: I had used the wrong button in the code snippets, corrected now @aug

Answer (score 0):

Yay!  I finally got it, thanks all for the supportive help!  To clarify, the answer I found here:
[Ajax response inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575928/ajax-response-inside-a-div)

> The selector should be .result not #result

It's the little things, thanks all!