# Ajax function to show result of a submission inside a particular div

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So I'm working on storing appointments of a calendar inside my db and I need to check the db for the name of the person before finishing the modal.

The code of the field, button and div where I need to show the result:

```
<div class="alinhar-esquerda"> 
   <input class="form-control" name="cpf_paciente" id="cpf_paciente" placeholder="" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="alinhar-direita">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="searchButton">Pesquisar</button>
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row" id="resultado" style="margin-top:5px;">
</div>
<?php
include("database2.php");
   if(isset($_POST["cpf_paciente"])){
      $cpf_paciente = $_POST["cpf_paciente"];
      $pesquisa = $connection->query("SELECT `id`, `cpf_paciente`, `nome_paciente`, `sobrenome_paciente` FROM  `pacientes` WHERE cpf_paciente='$cpf_paciente'");
      while($row = $pesquisa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         echo $row['nome_paciente'] . " " . $row['sobrenome_paciente'];
      }
   }
?>  
</div>
</div>
```

I need an Ajax code to receive the data from #submitButton input and then go through the php code inside the div #resultado without reloading the page, because all this is inside a modal which I'll send the results after getting the name of the person.

Tried something like this but no success:

```
$('#searchButton').submit(function() { // catch the data from submit event
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
  data: $(this).serialize(), // get the data
  type: $(this).attr('POST'), // POST
  url: $(this).attr(''), // no file to call
  success: function(response) { // on success..
      $('#resultado').html(response); // update the DIV
  }
});
});
```

Comment: just say `type: "POST"` ( or use $.post ) and you need to say the url where are you trying to post the result to. Whatever that url echoes will return in the response var.

Comment: `$(this).serialize()` are you sure? afaik, it must be a `form`. What errors do you see? `console.log` some?

Comment: Why is `$(this).attr('')` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$('#searchButton').click(function() { // catch the data from submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
      data: { cpf_paciente: $("#cpf_paciente").val() },
      type: "POST",
      url: '',
      success: function(response) { // on success..
          $('#resultado').html(response); // update the DIV
      }
    });
});
```

You can't use `$(this).serialize()` unless `this` is a `<form>`. It doesn't work with just a button (how would it know which inputs to serialize?).

The `type:` should just be `'POST`, since the button doesn't have a `POST` attribute.

The URL should be `''` to go to the same URL as the current page, `$(this).attr('')` is meaningless.

And the `submit` event only applies to a form. For a button you use `.click()`.

Comment: Oh, I see... but it seems like it's not sending the $_POST["cpf_paciente"] to the div so it triggers the php code.

Comment: Just to be clear, the user should insert the person document, then the select would return the full name so the user can confirm that's the right person, then the user can go down the modal and insert the observation for the appointment and at the end save it. The big problem is that it is a jquery plugin where I have limited power to edit, part because I don't understand all the jquery code(very new to that). I'd probably be able to do that with just php, but went with the plugin and ended up here.

Comment: You were using `.submit()` when it should be `.click()`. You submit forms, you click on buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the type and the url ->

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>contents/hello",
    data: "id=" + a_href,
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
        $(".result").html(data);    
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Not OKay');
    }
});​
```

Source -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10575968/3543355

Comment: What does `"id=" + a_href` have to do with with his code?

Comment: What is `base_url()`? That looks like it's from a particular framework.

Answer (score 0):

not understand what u want

but

```
<?php
 while($row = $pesquisa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
 {echo $row['nome_paciente'] . " " . $row['sobrenome_paciente'];
?>
```

if the result is

row 1 : qwe  ert

row 2 : asd dfg

js

```
$('#resultado').html(response);
```

this will display "qwe ert asd dfg"

and will do nothg just a text , if u want to regenerate code u and set up on php or u chg html code become js function so u can use the return str to explode and call the funtion to regenerate the element

for me both of this is easy way